# I'm wondering if a process’s BSS segment can grow during program execution

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I think the BSS segment only grow during compile time because it is only deal with variables that didn't initialise. Wright?

Comment: "Segments" are part of the binary/linker/loader system and have nothing to do with runtime execution. There are no "segments" in a running program memory image; there's only memory.

Comment: At least in the case of Windows, the "segments", or sections of most of the memory for a program are fixed in size. Again in the case of Windows, usually the heap (malloc, new, ...) is the only section of memory that can grow in size. The "segments" of a program in memory also have other attributes, like read only, read/write allowed, execute (instruction) allowed, ... .

Answer (score 0):

BSS is built by the compiler/linker. The program itself uses heap memory to grow.

In ancient days, heap memory was whatever was left-over between the stack and the end of the program itself, but these days, it's a bit more sophisticated and the stack is a fixed size, and heap memory is "anything not used for anything else" in the virtual space of the application (obviously subject to available memory in the system - 64-bit machines of today have MUCH more virtual space than physical memory, even if you make your entire typical home harddrive into swapspace)

Comment: What would happen if the program loads dynamically at some point a library? Where would an uninitialized static object of the DLL be stored?